# Changing the colour inside characters/Font

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

Firstly, I need to say I am not a web developer, but I have managed to create a HTML5 and CSS3 web site by learning from as many tutorials as possible, also hacking code together from Google searches.

On my web site I would like to display environmental information: **Temperature, Humidity, Air Pressure, etc.**

I would like to know if the following is possible and if someone can point me in the right direction?

What I would like to do is display the value of the Temp. and have the colour inside the digits related to the Temp.

So for example:

> If the Temp is below **10'C**, then colour inside the digits is **dark blue**
>
> If the Temp is between **10'C - 20'C**, then the colour inside the digits is **dark blue** at the **bottom** and fades to **light blue** at the **top** of the digits
>
> If the Temp is between **20'C - 30'C**, then the colour inside the digits is **light blue** at the **bottom** and fades to **orange** at the **top** of the digits
>
> If the Temp is between **30'C - 40'C**, then the colour inside the digits is **orange** at the **bottom** and fades to **red** at the **top** of the digits
>
> If the Temp is above **40'C** then the colour inside the digits is **red**

I hope it makes sense

Thank-you in advance

Gregg

Comment: show your html code for better suggestion...

Comment: So, is your question **How to get a weather widget**, or **how to style one you already have**? If it's one you already have, show us the code you already have.

Comment: did you try anything..

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I have been search the Internet for an example, or a base I can start from. I don't even know if it is even possible.

Comment: ur temp value (like 10'C - 20'C) coming from database or its just text??

Answer (score 0):

You can use some classes having different background colors like.

in css

```
.cssclassname1{
 background-color:blue;
}

.cssclassname2{
 background-color:blue;
}
```

in html

```
<div class="cssclassname1">below 10</div>
<div class="cssclassname2">above 10</div>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

i have tried something but i cant define all ur condiotions

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/fw6Pk/138/)

**HTML**

```
<p>If the Temp is below 10C, then colour inside the digits is dark blue.<br>
If the Temp is above 40C then the colour inside the digits is red</p>
```

**JS**

```
$.fn.wrapInTag = function(opts) {

    var o = $.extend({
        words: [],
        tag: '<strong>'
    }, opts);

    return this.each(function() {
        var html = $(this).html();
        for (var i = 0, len = o.words.length; i < len; i++) {
            var re = new RegExp(o.words[i], "gi");
            html = html.replace(re, o.tag + '$&' + o.tag.replace('<', '</'));
        }
        $(this).html(html);
    });

};

$('p').wrapInTag({
    words: ['10C', 'dark blue'],
    tag: '<span>'
});

$('p').wrapInTag({
    words: ['40C', 'red'],
    tag: '<span1>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a good effect using background-clip: text.

This is only supported by webkit and mozilla, though.

I have prepared a demo for Chrome. The CSS is

```
.text {
  font-size: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red, orange, yellow, lightblue, blue);
  background-size: 100% 400%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: colors 10s infinite linear;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colors {
    0% {background-position-y: 300%;}
    100% {background-position-y: 0%;}
}
```

In this demo, the background is clipped by the text, so that it will show only inside the numbers. To let it show we need also to make the text transparent. (and to make it a little nicer, we set a stroke around the font.

Then, we create a gradient background with the colors that you want, and just for fun we animate it.

In your code, the background-position would be set according to the temperature.

Notice that with that system, you can do it continous. (that is, a slightly different color for every temperature

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mQVLx/)

Answer (score 0):

Js Fiddle Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iAmMortos/SnfpV/2/)
(If your browser lacks webkit support, try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/iAmMortos/SnfpV/3/) instead.)

Probably the simplest way to control what the text looks like is to use css to define different styles (or colors as you've said) and then use javascript to set the class of a span tag around the temperature value text.

Some Sample HTML

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="[path to your .js file]"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="[path to your .css file]" />
</head>

<body onload="initialize();">
    <p>The temperature today is <span id="tempVal"></span></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Your javascript file:

```
var curTemp; // this will contain the current temperature
var curClassName; // the name of the class for that temperature (reflects css code below)
var valueContainer;

function initialize()
{
    valueContainer = document.getElementById("tempVal");
}

//... calculate or set the current temperature value here ...

if (curTemp < 10)
    curClassName = "freezing";
else if (curTemp >= 10 && curTemp < 20)
    curClassName = "cold";
else if (curTemp >= 20 && curTemp < 30)
    curClassName = "warm";
else if (curTemp >= 30 && curTemp <= 40)
    curClassName = "hot";
else if (curTemp > 40)
    curClassName = "scorching";

valueContainer.innerHTML = curTemp + "C";
valueContainer.setAttribute("class", curClassName);
```

This just leaves your CSS file. Now currently, the only way to achieve this gradient effect without using a canvas element is to use some webkit properties. These are not universally supported, so for maximum portability, I would simply use different solid colors rather than gradients, but here's the webkit example.

```
#tempVal 
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.freezing
{
    color: blue;
}
.cold
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, lightblue, blue);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.warm
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, orange, lightblue);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.hot
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, red, orange);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.scorching
{
    color: red;
}
```

Check out the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iAmMortos/SnfpV/2/)
If your numbers aren't coming up with a gradient color, it's because your browser doesn't support the webkit features.